# How to replace SSD boot disk when computer has RAID 1 data disk connected to it in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, ssd, raid

I am current using a computer (Intel I7) with a 60GB SSD and two 2TB drives in a RAID 1 configuration. The 60 GB drive has the Windows 7 operating system on it and the RAID disks are used for data.

I plan to replace the 60GB drive with a 250 Crucial MX200 drive. I plan to just do a clean install instead of trying to copy the 60GB over to the Crucial.

I have installed many hard drives before, but never with RAID. Are there any issues in this circumstance that I need to know about with respect to the RAID 1?

When I install the new SSD, do I essentially ignore the two drives in the RAID array, and install Windows 7 on the new SSD like I normally would, or are there steps to take with regards to the RAID? I plan to leave the RAID the way it is, using it for data, and not format or reinstall everything currently on it.

Comment: Just to be safe physically disconnect the raid drives during install of OS.

Comment: Good point. I'll remember to disconnect the RAID drives first.

Answer (score 2):

The RAID configuration is stored on the RAID volumes themselves, so there is no need to worry about copying it.

When you install the OS on the new SSD, all you should need to do is install the driver.

There is a chance that the new install will see the RAID volumes as "foreign", depending on the RAID controller.  In such a case, all you need to do is import the volume and they will come online.  How you would do so depends on the RAID controller's software.

Answer (score 1):

> Are there any issues in this circumstance that I need to know about
>   with respect to the RAID 1?

For RAID 1 itself: no.

But you do want to find out how those data drives are set in RAID.
These are the most used options:

1. Third party software RAID. In which case you will need to install the driver after installing the OS.
2. Software RAID via windows.  Install OS, connect drives. Should 'just work'.
3. Real hardware RAID: The RAID card handles the RAID 1 part. No need to change anything on that. Just install the correct driver for the RAID card after installing the OS.
4. Fake RAID, kept for last because this can give the most trouble.
   Fake RAID is software RAID (and thus needs drivers) with some support from the BIOS. This can be software RAID froma dedicated SATA controller, in which case see point 1. Or it can be done via the Intel chipset.
   In the last case you often have the choices for 'ancient legacy mode', 'Normal AHCI mode' and 'IRRST/RAID mode'. You do want the AHCI mode (which allows TRIM).
   That means that if you used the last then you want to change to AHCI mode and will loose the RAID array. Aka install the OS in AHCI mode, create a new RAID array using windows build in RAID and then copy back the data from backups.

It might very well not be option 4b. But whatever you do first check how the old RAID was set up and check if your backups are up to date and work when you try to restore.

Answer (score 0):

With a reinstall of the OS all programmes and games and such will need to be re installed. You could just clone your 60gb drive or even use something like easeus to move from a me drive to another. That would save you reinstalling everything.

But as mentioned above doing that separately should not affect the raid setup itself as long as that isn't handled by the OS level. You could have a hardware RAID or BIOS RAID. These should not be affected by what you want to achieve.

Comment: BIOS RAID is soften software RAID, with setup support from the BIOS. In which case the OP would have to install the correct drivers before accessing the data disks.

Comment: Even if the OP is using Microsoft's dynamic disks for the RAID the story is the same.  Just import the disks in Disk Manager.  RAID config is not saved in the registry or anything.  It's on the RAID volumes just like in a HW or BIOS RAID setup.  Even Linux LVMs do it this way.  RAID config is not dependent on the OS instance.